# How to make the width of an element in a container the width of the viewport?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to give the green bar in this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gC72u/ -  the width of the viewport?  That is, I want it to extend outside its container and continue all the way to the walls of the viewport.But it still needs to be a child of the container.

Thanks

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess you will need to use javascript.

Comment: I don't mind using JavaScript or jQuery.  What do you suggest?

Comment: @Mr. Allien answer seems to work fine (at least on chrome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I like the percentage approach, but you can always have a negative left-margin and an appropriate width. For instance:

```
div#box {
    margin-left: -50%;
    height:50px;
    width:200%;
    margin-top:50px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Disclaimer: I don't think percentages are a good paradigm if you have many containers.

Comment: While Mr Alien's solution works fine for the situation I described, what I didn't say initially is that I have to give the container relative positioning because it's full of other elements that are all positioned absolutely with respect to that container. Sheba's solution lets the container be relatively positioned.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can do this with CSS(only) is to use `position: absolute;` without using `position: relative;` for the parent element.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gC72u/1/)

```
div#box {
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:50px;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```